# Clang Format: attach brace to inline member function only

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is it possible with clang-format to attach the opening brace on inline class member functions only, without having the definition on a single line?
The intention here is to keep the class def compact but still allow setting breakpoints.

It doesn't look like its possible with BraceWrapping: Custom.. Just wondering if I missed something.

So for class member functions:

```
class Foo {
    // YES:
    int bar() {
        return 10;
    }
    // NO - cant set a breakpoint in the body
    int bar() { return 10; }
    // NO - too long
    int bar()
    {
        return 10;
    }
};
```

However, for top level functions, the brace is not attached:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

int Foo::bar()
{
    return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can but it will be little bit tricky.
I think you have to had two .clang format files one with

```
BreakBeforeBraces : Attach
```

and a second one with

```
BreakBeforeBraces : Allman
```

for example. you have to apply the first one to header file and the second one to the cpp file using clang-format command line (I have said little bit tricky)

Comment: Hmm ok - thank you for this.  I'll probably just have to live with longer class definitions!